# What is function(x) doing here exactly?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

In trying to tweak the output of `geom_bar()`, I come across some solutions that include `function(x)` as here where the x-axis labels get wrapped by use of stringr:

```
scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) str_wrap(x, width = 10)) +
```

What exactly is `function(x)` doing? It is simply saying that it's followed by a function to apply to x? But then what's x exactly, since it's the data defined in the original ggplot aes call, while here it's the label text?

Just when I think I understand something in R...

TIA.

Comment: You have the perfect username to ask this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entire expression goes together

```
function(x) str_wrap(x, width = 10)
```

is an anonymous function in R (a function with no name). The `labels=` parameter of `scale_x_discrete` can take a vector of characters, or a function. If a function, ggplot will pass in the default breaks as input It doesn't have to be named "x", you can call it whatever you want. So this would work as well

```
scale_x_discrete(labels = function(default_breaks) str_wrap(default_breaks, width = 10)) +
```

This is documented on the `?ggplot2::scale_x_discrete` help page.